# How can I use WWW::Mechanize to save an image's width, height, and bytes?

Tags: perl

I want to download images using WWW:Mechanize and to save into the file names their dimensions (width x height, bytes) but can't figure out how to extract the bytes into a readable format - my $img_bytes = format_bytes(????, precision => 2);
Thanks.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use Data::Dumper;
use Number::Format qw(format_bytes);
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = '';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $url );

my @img = $mech->find_all_images(url_regex => qr/\.(?:jpg|png)$/);

foreach my $img (@img) {
    my $filename = basename($img->url);
    $filename =~ /^(.*?)(\.\w+)$/; 
    my ($name,$ext) = ($1,$2); 
    my $img_width = $img->width;
    my $img_height = $img->height;
    my $img_size = ' ('.$img_width.' x '.$img_height.', '.$img_bytes.')';
    $mech->get( $img->url, ':content_file' => $name.$img_size.$ext );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suck the file out to a tempfile, and then run `my $bytes = -s $tempfilename;`, then rename the file.  And you do realize that `->width` and `->height` is from the tag, not the actual width and height of the image, right?

Here is how I would probably write your code:

```
#!/user/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use autodie;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use File::Basename;
use File::Temp     qw/tempfile/;
use Image::Info    qw/image_info dim/;
use Number::Format qw/format_bytes/;

my $url = 'http://www.perl.org';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( $url );

for my $img ($mech->find_all_images(url_regex => qr/\.(?:jpg|png)$/)) {
    my ($name, undef, $ext) = fileparse($img->url, "jpg", "png");

    (undef, my $temp) = tempfile;

    $mech->get( $img->url, ':content_file' => $temp );

    my ($w, $h) = dim image_info $temp;
    my $s       = format_bytes -s $temp, precision => 2;
    my $dim     = "($w x $h, $s)";

    rename $temp, "$name$dim.$ext";
}
```